# How to get a nice looking button?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I tried to use a custom image for a JButton, and it works well except for the fact that there is a white box around it. I am not sure how to fix this, and would like some help. (I create the button using new ImageButton("Quit", "src/button.png", 128, 64). The button is not resizable, and the image file is 256X128)

Button Class:

```
public class ImageButton extends JButton {

    Image image;
    ImageObserver imageObserver;

    public ImageButton(String text, String filename, int width, int height) {
        super(text, new ImageIcon(filename));
        setSize(width, height);
        setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Picture using getInsets override:

[image: Picture of the "Quit" button.]

Comment: Can you include snapshots of these images?

Comment: Maybe you have a white background in your image file?

Comment: I don't have a white background, I'm sure of that. I'm not sure how to use JavaFx, I'll look it up. I can't post any image of it right now because I'm not at home, but I will ASAP.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto Added images.

Comment: Examine [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Andrew helped me on this one. He pointed me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861852/add-a-complex-image-in-the-panel-with-buttons-around-it-in-one-customized-user/10862262#10862262) link, and it turns out I just have to disable the border and the content area. Thanks Andrew!

More info if you don't want to follow the link:
The main thing you should get out of this is that the border should be null like so: `button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setBorder(null);` and you should also set the content area to not be drawn: `button.setContentAreaFilled(false);` That's the main points for making your own custom button!

Answer (score 1):

This is more than likely due to fact that you have non-zero insets in the `ImageButton`. Try overriding `getInsets()`:

```
@Override
public Insets getInsets() {
   return new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I tested the button but did not see this effect. What layout are you using in the button's container? (I used `FlowLayout`) Consider posting a [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm using a GridBagLayout in Full-Screen Exclusive Mode, however I am painting the components in the JPanel I have via `j.paintComponents(bg);` with bg being `BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  Graphics2D bg = b.createGraphics();`

Answer (score 0):

Please use `paintComponent()` to draw a custom image in place of a default `JButton`. Also if you're going to paint on a `JPanel`, then use `JPanel.print()` the image on to the `JPanel`.

Comment: I read somewhere not to override paintComponent. Also, I'm not using paint().